# SSIS selective columns import from Excel

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am working with a client that has 175 different excel templates are used to create worksheets that I need to import into SQL 2008 R2.  There is one saving grace, there are 10 columns within the templates that a common to all 175 and they also are the columns I need to import into my SQL table.  Here is my question:  If I map only the columns that are common to all sheets to the database table, will SSIS ignore the other columns or will I need to somehow do something with these extra columns?

I developed a template for the user to utilize but evidently they need these other columns to be present for other applications besides the import I am doing.

The current SSIS process I have has a preparation SQL task to create the SQL table, then a data flow task that maps the Excel worksheet columns and an import task that takes the mapped columns and updates the table.

My guess is that if I create the table with only the columns I need, adjust the Excel mapping to only select the columns I have available in the table, the import will only move those columns and as a result, I will have what I need regardless of which template is used.

Has anyone done something like this before?  This process is a stop gap for approximately 6 months until the new system is available which will share this data between the two systems.

Thanks in advance to any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a SQL statement to select from your Excel table/range/sheet then you should be able to make the tables appear consistent to SSIS by only selecting the required columns.

However this select statement will need to know the name of the range or sheet so this will need to be consistent.

If this is not possible I suggest you create a script that opens the Excel files and deletes all the unneeded columns.. this course is liable to crash if everything isn't just right or if it isn't written defensively.

Comment: Thanks.  Last night I imported about 4 of the 175 sheets.  They are pretty consistent with naming on the critical columns so I am able to map just the columns I need.  I am continuing testing today, but this seems to work.  I am curious about what you mean by writing defensively.

Comment: Wikipedia has a good explanation :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming
Your code tries to anticipate for every possible failure you can think of. So you end up with 80% of your code as error handling. I only mentioned it, because in a prior question about a trigger, a poster said only 1 row would ever be inserted into his table, so he didn't need to cater for multiple rows... and I said it wasn't very defensive programming. To be honest it shouldn't even have a special name, all code should be written that way!

Comment: You have to be particularly defensive when importing Excel as data quality is not that good, people create macros and formulas, skip lines, all kinds of things you need to allow for in your code.